# Nodejs - how to send JSON object via express response

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I send a JSON object via express response `(res.send)` is it possible?

Currently I send the data into console logs `(console.log(JSON.stringify(row))`, but I would like to use `res.send` to be able to display the data on my webpage.

logs :

```
2020-05-20T16:43:15.272145+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id":1,"name":"Athlestan","joined":"2020-05-19T08:42:12.705Z","lastvisit":null,"counter":0}
2020-05-20T16:43:15.272551+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id":2,"name":"Ragnar","joined":"2020-05-19T08:42:12.705Z","lastvisit":null,"counter":0}
2020-05-20T16:43:15.272765+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id":3,"name":"Rollo","joined":"2020-05-19T08:42:12.705Z","lastvisit":null,"counter":0}
2020-05-20T16:43:15.272997+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id":4,"name":"Lagertha","joined":"2020-05-19T08:42:12.705Z","lastvisit":null,"counter":0}
```

index.js :

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const Client = require('pg').Pool 


const client = new Client({
connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
})

client.connect();

client.query('SELECT * FROM users;', (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  for (let row of res.rows) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
  }
  client.end();
});

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.send("Heroku app with github!");
});

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: When I type your exact question into Google, it gives me a nice tutorial on res.json() as the first result.

Answer (score 1):

Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using JSON.stringify().

The parameter can be any JSON type, including object, array, string, Boolean, number, or null, and you can also use it to convert other values to JSON.

Examples:

```js
res.json(null)
res.json({ user: 'tobi' })
res.status(500).json({ error: 'message' })
```

[More info](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#res.json)